# Chromecast: how to select a CastDevice without a CastButton

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I'm working on an App where i want to stream a specific video, which is located on my mobile device. I want to stream this video with the help of ChromeCast to a projector. I've done the Google Chromecast Tutorials (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#0 for example) and already looked for an answer to my Question but there wasn't the perfect answer to solve my problem in my opinion.

There are a few solutions in other coding languages but not especially for java.

My **problem with the Google Cast API is: I want to select my ChromeCast without pressing the Cast Button in the OptionMenu**, which appears to select one of the ChromeCasts in the Network.

- I just found out, that the setRouteSelector-Methode from the class CastButtonFactory is a part to select the Device. But i can't find out, how to select the device automatically.

Here is my Code where the CastButton appears (created in the OnCreateOptionsMenu-Method)(It's just the Code to Connect to the ChromeCast. I didn't implement the Code for selecting and streaming the video yet):

Can anyone help me?

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CastSession mCastSession;
private CastContext mCastContext;
private SessionManager mSessionManager;

private final SessionManagerListener mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListenerImpl();

private class SessionManagerListenerImpl implements SessionManagerListener{

    @Override
    public void onSessionStarting(Session session) {}

    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(Session session, String sessionId) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStartFailed(Session session, int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onSessionEnding(Session session) {}

    @Override
    public void onSessionEnded(Session session, int error) {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionResuming(Session session, String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onSessionResumed(Session session, boolean wasSuspended) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionResumeFailed(Session session, int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onSessionSuspended(Session session, int i) {}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
    mCastContext.registerLifecycleCallbacksBeforeIceCreamSandwich(this, savedInstanceState);
    mSessionManager = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this).getSessionManager();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    mCastSession = mCastContext.getSessionManager().getCurrentCastSession();
    mSessionManager.addSessionManagerListener(mSessionManagerListener);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mSessionManager.removeSessionManagerListener(mSessionManagerListener);
    mCastSession = null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
}

@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(),
            menu,
            R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: What is the reason that you want to do that, which is against the UX guidelines established by the cast team? Also note that doing so will be against Terms of Service, item 3.4.8 (see https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/terms)

Comment: i want to play my video, if someone enters a room. So it's better, that my device automatically connects with my app. I don't want to select a device first, when a "tester" enters my room, because i have to send a signal to another app at a definite time. 
I have to clarify the "against the Terms of Service" thing, but thank you for the hint! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with [SDK v2](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_sender). Check out the source code for [MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/com/android/internal/app/MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment.java), the UI element that lets users select a Cast device. You'll want to create a `MediaRouter.Callback`, and override  `onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo newRoute)`. If the new route is not the default route, select it with `mMediaRouter.selectRoute(newRoute)`. This will connect you to the receiver device without any user interaction.

This should work for testing, but please don't do this in a production app. @AliNaddaf correctly notes this is against the UX guidelines and Google Cast terms of service (you can imagine the potential for abuse if apps are permitted to start casting without the user's consent).

Comment: i accidentally pressed the enter key.... sorry. 
is there a way to list all the possible routes? something like "getRoutes()", so that i can select the route i want to connect to?
If not, is the RouteInfo the name of the Chromecast or how do i get the suitable route?
by the way, we decided us to mirror the phone screen.It's way easier than this attempt, i think. But it's in my personal interest to get a approach to my problem.

Comment: `MediaRouter.RouteInfo` describes the route metadata; `RouteInfo.getName()` returns the name. Follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_sender) up to the section "Handling Device Selection". Then, in `MyMediaRouterCallback`, override the method `onRouteAdded`, with: `if (!newRoute.equals(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute()) mMediaRouter.select(newRoute);` I don't know of a `getRoutes()` method. If you want to write your own `getRoutes()`, add `newRoute` to a `Set<RouteInfo>` whenever a new route is added, then define `getRoutes()` to return the set.

Comment: I finally solved it. I just needed the Callback as a variable then i added the Callback in the onStart()-method to the MediaRouter. Like you said you need to override the onRouteAdded method, but not exactly with your code because you're assuming, that there is only one ChromeCast. If there are more than one, you need to get the Uniqe Id from the ChromeCast you want to connect to. I got this ID by testing another app and Logging the ID with: Log.d(TAG, "onRouteAdded: route=" + route); Then just put an if-else state around and set the current route with: mediaRouter.selectRoute(route). Thanks!